# Using genisoimage and cdrecord in Linux

Tags: linux, audio, encryption, fedora

I want to perform an encrypted multisession CD by first using genisoimage followed by cdrecord libraries.

Here are the steps that are I would need to do.

```
sudo su -c yum install cdrecord
sudo apt-get install loop-aes-utils aespipe 
sudo modprobe cryptoloop
genisoimage -quiet -r ~/Desktop | aespipe -T -e aes256 > image.iso
genisoimage -quiet -r ~/Desktop | cdrecord dev=ATAPI:0,1,0 -v -multi -pad `enter code here`-data -
sudo mkdir /media/iso
sudo mount -o loop,encryption=aes256 image.iso /media/iso
wodim --devices
wodim dev=/dev/sg1 image.iso
cdrecord dev=ATAPI:0,1,0 -v -audio track*wav
cdrecord dev=ATAPI:0,1,0 -v -audio track01.cdda.wav track01.cdda.wav `enter code here`middle.wav last.wav
cdrecord dev=ATAPI:0,1,0 -v -dao -audio track*wav
cdrecord -v -eject speed=4 dev=0,4,0 -multi cd-iso-image-file-1.iso 
cdrecord dev=0,4,0 -msinfo 
mkisofs -J -r -V SecondBurn -o cd-iso-image-file-2.iso -C 0,16774 -M `enter code here`0,4,0 <directory-with-files-to-add>
cdrecord -v -dummy dev=2,0 cdimage.raw -audio track*.cdaudio
```

I do hope this will be okay.  If anybody has any questions or comments regarding this task, please do not hesitate to reply.

JohnDB

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I have not tried it in Linux yet. I have realized that all versions of Windows operating systems do not have libraries nor support multisession optical disc burning other than UNIX and its cousins. Is that true?